# meteor can't find global variable in node_modules

Tags: meteor

I want to use packages such as shelljs(https://atmospherejs.com/izzilab/shelljs) but I am getting an error, "can't find variable: shell". It is an npm package wrapped around for Meteor. Why wouldn't the variable be global scoped though?

Does anyone know what the best way to list all files in a local directory is within meteor client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your project runs on the version of meteor `1.3` and you're writing everything in the imports folder, then you need to use `export/import` feature of `es6` modules.

Comment: My project is running on meteor 1.2. Would I still need to use that feature?